# ActiveMQ message propagation in a network of brokers

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, messaging, broker

We've set up a hub and spoke topology with two hubs for redundancy. **All nodes** that connect to the network have a static network connection to the two hubs.

If we bring up a consumer for a particular topic produced by another spoke and then drop one of the hubs, sometimes the consumer will stop getting data.  If bringing down hub A causes the consumer to stop receiving data, bringing A back up will restore the consumer's feed.  Bringing B down has no effect on the feed.  It seems to be inconsistent which hub may affect the consumer.

We expected that with a network of brokers a consumer should always get data as long as a producer is on the network and both are connected to one or more hubs. **Is this expectation correct or do we need to change our topology?**

Every node has a network connector that looks like this:

```
static:(tcp://hub1,tcp://hub2)
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that staticallyIncludedDestinations on the network connector configuration fixes the issue.  Subscriptions are managed solely on the broker with the consumer attached and aren't impacted by a hub going down.

4/25 Update: However network traffic drastically increased.  Messages are being forwarded continuously until their TTL is reached.  Not really the best solution...